# Can a dependant get a visa and travel alone to Schengen?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, multiple-entry, uk-residents

My wife and myself are Indian citizens living in UK on resident permits. We are planning to travel to the Netherlands (duration ten days) together in June and applying at the Netherlands Embassy for the visas. Before that my wife (dependant) wants to travel to Denmark for three days.

Can she apply for a visa along with me at the Netherlands Embassy, as she is a dependant, and travel alone to Denmark on same visa as a first port of entry?

I will be showing as the sponsor of her trips to Denmark and he Netherlands.

Will there be an issue with the visa application as I am not accompanying her to Denmark?

Comment: She can travel independently if she gets a Schengen

Comment: Yes, just put it on her visa application.

Comment: Why would it matter whether you are accompanying her or not?

Comment: @phoog, the OP may have it cross-wired to the EU family permit, hence the confusion

Answer (score 2):

For a Schengen itinerary covering more than one country, the rule is that the traveler must apply at the consulate of the country that is the *main destination* of the itinerary, if it is possible to determine a main destination.  This rule is stated in Article 5 of the [Schengen Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20131018).

In your wife's case, the Netherlands is her main destination, so she should apply there.

Your wife's visa application will of course be subject to all the normal requirements to show her ability to pay for the trip, including travel insurance, and her intention to depart the Schengen area at the conclusion of her trip.  The fact that you are not accompanying her to Denmark does not seem likely to raise any questions in this regard.